# Mod Operator in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query

What is the correct syntax in MongoDB to return all queries that meet the following criteria:

```
a % 4 >= 2
```

I tried using below command, but it returns empty

```
db.data.find( { a : { $mod : [ 4, { $gte : 2 } ] } } );
```

Another option would be using Javascript expression as follow:

```
db.data.find( "this.a % 4 >= 2" );
```

Javascript expression works and returns expected documents, but it does not work from within PyMongo.

MongoDB version 2.0.4
PyMongo version 2.1.1

Comment: a % 4 >= 3 is equivalent to the more efficient a % 4 == 3 by the way.  It's not possible for a % 4 to be > 3.

Comment: Ok, bad example, I fixed the example above to a % 4 >= 2

Comment: Just curios: what do you use the query for? Personally I have never needed $mod. Thus I would like to know what it is used for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this currently with a simple query, and you'll have to use your javascript version instead. You should be able to do that with PyMongo with the [where](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.where) method on the created cursor. F.e.:

```
cursor = collection.find().where( "this.a % 4 >= 2" );
```

Comment: I hope MongoDB will provide support for bitwise operation in the future, but this work around will do for the moment. Thanks, it works.

Comment: MongoDB does support simple bitwise operators for modifying. For queries, the answer is at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3518

Answer (score 3):

To use a where expression in PyMongo, try this: `{ $where: "this.a % 4 >= 2" }`

The `$mod` operator simply doesn't work with conditionals like that. You have three choices:

1. Use a where expression
2. Use an expression like these:

   ```
   db.data.find( { $or : [ { a : { $mod : [ 4, 2 ] } },
                           { a : { $mod : [ 4, 3 ] } }
                         ] } );

   db.data.find( { $and : [ { a : { $not : { $mod : [ 4, 0 ] } } },
                            { a : { $not : { $mod : [ 4, 1 ] } } }
                          ] } );
   ```
3. Store `a % 4` in its own field.

Comment: The answer with `$or` above is the best one, if the numbers are small, because it doesn't involve Javascript evaluation.